# Erro al usar Login de Facebook

Tags: android-studio, firebase, hash, facebook-api

[image: Me Indica el error de la imagen cuando instalo la app en otro dispositivo, en mi dispositivo personal es el unico donde me deja iniciar sesion]

Cuando le doy al Botón de Inicio de Sesión con Facebook desde mi App creada con Android Studio me aparece este error, sin embargo el código hash es el correcto ya lo confirme varias veces, lo raro es que tengo mi teléfono personal y con mi teléfono personal si me deja Loguearme con Facebook el error únicamente me lo indica en cualquier otro dispositivo que no se el mío, a los cuales les indica el error de la imagen

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que quiero lograr es que cualquier dispositivo en el que se instale la App pueda hacer uso del Botón login con Facebook lo cual por el momento no logro solucionar, ya que solo me deja ocupar la función desde un teléfono unicamente, en el resto me indica que la App no está disponible como aparece en la imagen, estuve revisando el foro para ver si a alguien más le había pasado pero no pude encontrar nada, pensé que era el hash de autentificacion, pero dado que en un dispositivo si me funciona descarte esa posibilidad, con la implementación lo seguí de la documentación oficial y tengo todo configurado en el proyecto de Facebook developers tal y como especifican las documentaciones

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).